# Programatically set destination as "Print as pdf" and save to a designated path on windows file system

Tags: javascript, browser, printing, batch-processing

Our Application opens up the print dialog box using JavaScript. Can we programmatically skip the dialog box and set the destination printer as "Save as PDF" and dynamically save the file to a designated folder on windows file system.

We will be OK if this is supported in at least one browser. This is needed so that we can automate printing of multiple documents from the system. Any help with this matter is appreciated.

Comment: That will be a security issue, if you can access the disk without the knowledge of the user

Comment: ^ although every browser I know never let us do that, because this causes security issue